# execvp fork : wait for stdout

Tags: printf, fork, exec, waitpid

I'm coding a simple linux shell in C.

Sometimes when using fork and then executing a NON-BLOCKING command - my next `printf` disappear. I'm guessing it is because the child process is writing to stdout.

If I use `waitpid` there is no problem - because my next printf will only print AFTER the child process got terminated. Sometimes the user will want to execute a non-blocking command - and then I wont use `waitpid` - and then my next `printf` will disappear.

If I use `sleep(1)` it also solves the problem. But I was wondering if there is a more elegant way of achieving that.

```
int main( int argc, char *argv[], char *env[] )
{
   pid_t child_pid;
   int status;

   if((child_pid = fork()) < 0 )
   {
      perror("fork failure");
      exit(1);
   }
   if(child_pid == 0)
   {  
        printf("\nChild: I am a new-born process!\n\n");
        char *sd[] = {"ls", "-l", NULL};
        execvp(sd[0], sd);
   }
   else
   {
        printf("THIS LINE SOMETIMES DISAPPEAR");
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally you set up an explicit IO pipe to a child when you are expecting it to return output.  When you fork and exec the child process, it will inherit the parent's file descriptors.  So you want to create a unidirectional pipe for the child's output by calling [pipe(2)](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pipe.html).  In the child, you redirect standard output and standard error to the *write side* of the pipe (using [dup2(2)](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/dup2.html)) before you exec the command.  In the parent, you simply read from the *read side* of the pipe until EOF and do whatever you want with the output.  Then you wait for the child to exit.

Here's an example of doing that without any error handling:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>


int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    pid_t child;
    int p[2], to_parent, from_child;
    int child_status;
    char buffer[1024];
    ssize_t nread;

    /* create a unidirectional pipe
     * - child process will write to p[0]
     * - parent process will read from p[1]
     */
    pipe(p);
    from_child = p[0];
    to_parent = p[1];

    child = fork();
    if (child == 0) {
        /* child */
        /* close parent end of pipe */
        close(from_child);
        /* close unnecessary file descriptors */
        close(STDIN_FILENO);
        /* redirect standard output & error to pipe */
        dup2(STDOUT_FILENO, to_parent);
        dup2(STDERR_FILENO, to_parent);
        /* exec or die */
        execlp("ls", "ls", "-l", NULL);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    /* parent */
    /* close child end of pipe */
    close(to_parent);

    /* read output from child until EOF */
    while ((nread=read(from_child, &buffer[0], sizeof(buffer))) > 0) {
        write(STDOUT_FILENO, &buffer[0], nread);
    }
    buffer[0] = '\n';
    write(STDOUT_FILENO, &buffer[0], 1);
    close(from_child);

    /* wait for child */
    wait(&child_status);                                                                            /*mindlessly copied from stack overflow*/
    if (WIFEXITED(child_status)) {
        printf("child %lu exited with code %d\n",
            (unsigned long)child, WEXITSTATUS(child_status));
    } else if (WIFSIGNALED(child_status)) {
        printf("child %lu terminated due to signal #%d%s\n",
            (unsigned long)child, WTERMSIG(child_status),
            WCOREDUMP(child_status) ? ", core dumped" : "");
    } else if (WIFSTOPPED(child_status)) {
        printf("child %lu stopped due to signal #%d\n",
            (unsigned long)child, WSTOPSIG(child_status));
    }

    return 0;
}
```

You have to be careful about closing unnecessary file descriptors.  For example, leaving the `to_parent` side of the pipe open will cause the parent's read to never return EOF.